# How to update column text value with concatenation of multiple columns text values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

For e.g. my table structure is like

```
id(int, auto_increment), 
first_name(text), 
last_name(text), 
address(text), 
merged_content(text)
```

I have thousands of rows which have `first_name`, `last_name` and `address` entries already filled.
**I want to update concatenated text in `merged_content`**. I know, how to do this in PHP, but updating thousands of records (apprx 30K) is very time consuming.

So, I was hoping **if something like this can be achieved in MySql directly** -

```
Update table_x set merged_content="<p>" + first_name + " " + last_name + "</p><p><b>Address -</b> " + address + "</p>"
```

Obviously the above query is wrong, and not working, but I couldn't even find anything else, that I could try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql has built-in function called `concat` which you can use, something as

```
Update table_x 
set 
merged_content=
concat('<p>',first_name,' ',last_name,'</p><p><b>Address -</b> ',address,'</p>');
```

Comment: Yes it's working. I will accept as an answer after SO time-limit allows me. Meanwhile, I noticed if any column has null values (e.g. address in a particular row is `NULL`), then that row is not updated. Is there anyway (in mysql) to show only `concat` text of `first_name` and `last_name` only, other than updating `Null` values of `address` to "". Thanks.

Comment: Yes when you do concat with null the result is null, you can use `ifnull` or `coalesce` function to covert null to something else.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. Just came to know that `MySql` also has `If else` and `case`statements

Comment: I just read your comment. I will look into `ifnull` and `coalesce` function. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try this commands on mysql you will understand more about this `select concat('aa',null);` and then `select concat('aa',coalesce(null,''));`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation operator in sql is not `+` . It s `||`

Replace all the `+` with `||` to make the query work

Comment: I just tried with `||`. but it's updating as `1` not the actual concatenated text. Extra info - previously with `+` it was updating as `0`. and I confirm that my `merged_content` has type `text` not `integer`